# HVAC running loud

Tags: hvac

I live in an apartment building with in-unit HVAC system. During the operations, when the fan is on, it is very loud. Is that normal (my neighbors' is whisper quite)? Is there something I can do, or shall pay attention to?

Comment: It may be the fan, the compressor, a rattling housing, or something else.  More details are needed.  If you haven't had a service tech look at it lately, now may be a good time to call one.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks for the response. I guess the problem is the fan. Am I doing wrong to set the fan on "auto" position? What will happen, if I switch the control in another direction, which says "on"? I am sort of confused. Maybe I shall just call the service.

Comment: For the usual (North American, anyway) meaning of "apartment building" (rental units, not owned) this is "call building maintenance/management" rather than DIY as it's part of the building systems. If you own, that might still be the correct direction, depending on the ownership association setup, or you might need to arrange service yourself.

Comment: Only very recently have they become whisper quite. I could tell you how loud it's going to be from the paint color on the unit. If it's loud before the fan even starts, maybe you could use a new inducer blower. If it whistles coming out of the vents, try pleated filters instead of fiberglass.

Comment: @Mazura Can you elaborate the function of "inducer blower", and causes and symptoms of wear/damage? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Loose screws, grills, and covers tend to buzz so check while running by pushing on them.

Comment: Be aware that this "was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." While I see nothing wrong with it as it stands (and why they're reviewed by people, not auto-deleted by the system), but one-sentence answers do tend to get looked down on here. Just something to be aware of for the future.